# How to use generic Queue where the type also has a generic paramater?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, generics, queue

I have a situation where I would like to have a member property on my class that utilizes the generic `Queue<T>` provided by .Net, however, my type is also generic.

For example:

I want to declare my class having a member property being a Queue instance;

```cs
public class SomeServiceThing: Singleton<SomeServiceThing>
{
    private Queue<SomeType<T>> = new Queue<SomeType<T>>();

    ....

    private void EnqueueEvent<T>(SomeType<T> _event)
    {
        pendingEvents.Enqueue(_event);
        lastEventQueued = DateTime.Now;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (someConditionIsMet)
        {
            // flush the queue and perform an operation with each pending event
        }
    }
}
```

The compiler error I received is "Cannot resolve symbol 'T'", which makes sense as T cannot be derived when the class is instantiated, but then I would ask how would you go about using Queue in this way when T itself has a generic parameter?

Comment: Try `private void EnqueueEvent(SomeType<T> _event)`. Is the surrounding class also generic?

Comment: The surrounding class itself is not also generic. I've updated the question/example to reference this.

Comment: I don't see how your class can compile. Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: @Vigs what is your actual goal with it?

Answer (score 2):

you should change the `SomeServiceThing` class to `SomeServiceThing<T>`

```cs
public class SomeServiceThing<T> : Singleton<SomeServiceThing<T>>
{
    private Queue<SomeType<T>> pendingEvents = new Queue<SomeType<T>>();

    private void EnqueueEvent(SomeType<T> _event)
    {
        pendingEvents.Enqueue(_event);
        lastEventQueued = DateTime.Now;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (someConditionIsMet)
        {
            // flush the queue and perform an operation with each pending event
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've updated my question to reference this now, but I need to be able to later reference the events in the queue and operate on them while also flushing the queue. How would you recommend going about accessing the queue without having an instance on the class? When I need to access the queue to iterate, I won't have `T` available to invoke `pendingEvents<SomeType<T>>()`.

Answer (score 0):

If you use T in your queue, you have to define it already on class level and not on method level:

```
public class SomeServiceThing<T>: Singleton<SomeServiceThing<T>>
{
    private Queue<SomeType<T>> = new Queue<SomeType<T>>();

    ....

    private void EnqueueEvent(SomeType<T> _event)
    {
        pendingEvents.Enqueue(_event);
        lastEventQueued = DateTime.Now;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (someConditionIsMet)
        {
            // flush the queue and perform an operation with each pending event
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class SomeServiceThing<T>: Singleton<SomeServiceThing>
{
    private Queue<SomeType<T>> = new Queue<SomeType<T>>();

....

    private void EnqueueEvent(SomeType<T> _event)
    {
        pendingEvents.Enqueue(_event);
        lastEventQueued = DateTime.Now;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (someConditionIsMet)
        {
        // flush the queue and perform an operation with each pending event
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want one `SomeServiceThing` instead of one `SomeServiceThing` per type T, make your generic `SomeType<T>` implement an interface, and use that interface as the type T for the queue.

```
public class SomeServiceThing: Singleton<SomeServiceThing>
{
    private Queue<ISomeType> = new Queue<ISomeType>();

    ....

    private void EnqueueEvent<T>(ISomeType _event)
    {
```

And then define SomeType like:

```
public class SomeType<T>: ISomeType
{
```